# SQL Like vs C# Contains difference

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I have following SQL in C#,

```
var str= QueryExecutor.Query<string>("SELECT SomeColumn from Somtable WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '%abc_def%'", new { }, CommandType.Text).FirstOrDefault();
            if (str.Contains("abc_def"))
            {

            }
```

Now I get the big string but `str.Contains("abc_def")` returns false. The column is NVARCHAR(MAX). Why contains and LIKE differ?

Comment: They differ because they differ. They don't have the same rules. `LIKE` follows case sensitivity configuration for the database and/or column in question, and you also have a wildcard in there, the underscore. `string.Contains` uses an exact match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably missing that `_` is a wildcard for SQL `LIKE` that matches exactly one character.

So, `LIKE '%abc_def%'` can match *any* character between the two:

```
abc1def
abcZdef
abc&def
abc_def
```

To match an underscore in SQL Server using `LIKE`, you can use one of the following:

```
SomeColumn LIKE '%abc[_]def%'             -- use a character class
SomeColumn LIKE '%abc$_def%' ESCAPE '$'   -- use an escape character
```

Or, you can use `charindex()`:

```
CHARINDEX('abc_def', SomeColumn) > 0
```

Comment: Additionally, SQL Server is typically configured as case **in**sensitive.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yep.  Then they have to get into collations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017